Partitions in Oracle
I have a large table in Oracle that is loaded daily with recent data. This table is partitioned by a single field, 'Source', using the 'PARTITION BY LIST' type. The partitions are divided into 'Source = 'afk'' and 'Source = 'ert''. To load data where 'Source' is 'afk', the data is inserted directly into the table without any issues. However, to load data where 'Source' is 'ert', we first truncate the corresponding partition and then rebuild the table's primary key (PK). After loading the data, we have noticed that all indexes on the table, except for the primary key, become unusable. The table has about 10 additional indexes.
Do you have any suggestions on how to address this issue?
What we are currently doing every day is rebuilding each of the affected indexes, but for some, the rebuild time is very long. Overall, it takes us about 5 hours to rebuild all the indexes.

To work with individual partitions (move, truncate, exchange, drop) you will always invalidate global indexes, making them unusuable (the physical index segment is actually dropped and only the definition remains in an UNUSABLE state). This is because indexes have ROWIDs that point to physical row locations within files, and the above kinds of DDL operations either drop or create new segments in new locations, totally changing the ROWIDs, thus making those pointers in those indexes point to nothing. That's why they go invalid. This forces you to rebuild them in order to pick up the new ROWIDs, but rebuilding global indexes on a large partitioned table is often too much work, as you've found it to be.
In these situations, you simply need to make your indexes all LOCAL. Script all the indexes out, add the keyword LOCAL, drop the current ones and recreate them using the script. Once they are all local, only the index partitions belonging to the impacted table partition will be affected. The index partitions in all the other table partitions will be untouched and remain usable.
Now there are a couple downsides to local indexes:

If you have any high-frequency (in a loop) SQL against a selective index (like a PK) the # of index seeks (binary searches) is multiplied by the # of partitions. If you have hundreds of partitions and are doing hundreds of thousands or millions of queries, the overhead of checking every single index partition every single time can really make that slow. However, in most cases a massive partitioned table (1) isn't normally queried in this row-by-row fashion, (2) queries often ask for less selective predicates that require a lot of table I/O anyway so the index work is relatively minor in comparison, or (3) queries in a warehouse are often doing full scans so indexes are not involved. And, if your query includes an equality predicate on the partitioning key and so partition-prunes, the effect is removed - you will seek a single index segment and it's just as fast as a global index. So it all depends on how the table is used.
A unique index (e.g., your PK) cannot enforce its uniqueness across multiple index segments, so Oracle will require you to expand your index definition to include the partitioning key. If your partition key column is not already part of your PK, that means changing your entity-integrity protection level, which loosens to the point of losing that protection. On the other hand, partitioning is typical of warehouse situations where entity-integrity is less crucial because data is secondary (it comes from elsewhere, it's not the source of record).

But if you can live with the above ramifications of using local indexes, they are a life-saver when it comes to reducing your maintenance time for working with partitions.

While I agree with everything Paul said above you can call this wrapper, which calls a function to rebuild UNUSABLE indexes. Ideally you should do it right after your load or schedule it whenever appropriate.
Note its hardcoded for 4 parallel processes you should adjust to fit your requirements.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl(p_cmd varchar2) 
 authid current_user
is
t1 pls_integer;
BEGIN 
t1 := dbms_utility.get_time; 

dbms_output.put_line(p_cmd);

 execute immediate p_cmd;

dbms_output.put_line((dbms_utility.get_time - t1)/100 || ' seconds');

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rebuild_index
authid current_user
is

BEGIN 
        for i in (
            select index_owner, index_name, partition_name, 'partition' ddl_type
           from all_ind_partitions
           where status = 'UNUSABLE'
           union all
           select owner, index_name, null, null
           from all_indexes
           where status = 'UNUSABLE'
       )
       loop
         if i.ddl_type is null then
          ddl('alter index '||i.index_owner||'.'||i.index_name||' rebuild parallel 4 online');
         else
          ddl('alter index '||i.index_owner||'.'||i.index_name||' modify '||i.ddl_type||' '||i.partition_name||' rebuild parallel 4 online');
         end if;
       end loop;
 END;
/


